# mac and iphone development books 2009

Tags: iphone, macos

What the best books available right now on Mac and iPhone development ?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two books were good:

- [iPhone SDK Application
  Development](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596154059/?CMP=AFC-ak_book&ATT=iPhone+SDK+Application+Development%2c)
- [iPhone In Action](http://www.manning.com/callen/)

The Apple online docs are actually pretty good too:

- http://developer.apple.com/iphone/

I'd stay away from this one, I didn't think it was very good:

- [Programming in Objective C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider some of these:  http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/book

Answer (score 1):

In this order:

- Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X (The Bible)
- Beginning iPhone Development (Long-winded but great for beginners)
- iPhone SDK Development (Starts nicely, but gets a little too deep too fast. Still in beta)
- Programming in Objective-C (Only down so far because I couldn't get through the first few chapters. Recommended by many, good for total programming beginners)
- iPhone Cookbook (Full of mistakes, but good for learning stuff closer to the code)
- iPhone in Action (I didn't learn anything from this book. Might be good for programming for Mobile Safari)
- Learning Cocoa with Objective-C (Avoid)

This is mainly an iPhone list, but several are more general books.

Answer (score 0):

The [iPhone SDK Development](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development) looks very nice. I did not read it, but read a lot promising about it on the blog of one of the authors, [Chris Adamson](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/). The blog itself is very good reading for everybody interested in iPhone sound programming.