# How can I start developing a simple APP on iphone?

Tags: iphone

How can I start developing a simple APP on iphone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with these previous answers on SO:

- [Getting started with iphone dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development)
- [How to articles for iphone dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)
- [Best book/article to learn iphone dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758748/best-book-or-article-to-learn-iphone-development)

Answer (score 0):

Buy a Mac, install XCode, then go to [IPhone tutorial blogs](http://icodeblog.com/) to learn. That should be it.

Comment: I think its enough to install mac os with vmware (or other virtualization software)

Comment: yeah, that may be a solution.

Comment: Seems like that I have to buy a Mac first...

Comment: personally, I can tell you to install hackintosh. But it is not easy, illegal.

Comment: ya, installing mac on VMware is working good. it needs only USB mouse & keyBoard.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you are better off reading a book than browsing blogs when starting to learn a new technology from scratch.

Therefore my recommendation would be to buy a Mac, install XCode, then buy a [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409003/mac-and-iphone-development-books-2009) on IPhone programming.

Comment: which book will you prefer adrian if you are in iPhone for near about 9 months in iPhone...

Comment: @Suresh: Have a look at the SO thread I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making an web-app instead. It's 80 percent of the functionality of an real app with 20 percent the effort for anyone new to iOS.

If you want to learn iOS then buy a Mac, install xCode and go with the flow. Watch Stanfords CS193P course on iTunes and do the assignments as a start.